# Calling Class method from other file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help with plugins, classes, and methods in PHP.

I am trying to call a method from a plugin file from one of my own functions but I doesn't seem to make it work.

PS. The plugin that is being used is Learndash-Group-Registration and not Woocommerce. Woocommerce is used for it's products and orders.

**This is the file where I try to call the method: (file.php)**

```
    $args = array(
      'order_id' => 1234,
    );
    include '/wp-content/plugins/ld-
group-registration/modules/class-wdm-woocommerce.php';

WdmLdWooCommerce::wdmCourseOrderCompletedCreateGroup( $args[ 'order_id' ] );
```

**class-wdm-woocommerce.php**

```
    <?php
namespace wisdmlabs\ldgroups;

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;
if (!class_exists('WdmLdWooCommerce')) {
    class WdmLdWooCommerce
    {
        public function wdmCourseOrderCompletedCreateGroup($order_id)
        {
            if ($this->wdmIsRenewalOrder($order_id)) {
                return;
            }
            $order = new \WC_Order($order_id);
            $product_id = null;
            $group_data = array();
            $items = $order->get_items();
            $group_creation_done = get_post_meta($order_id, 'wdm_successful_group_creation', true);

            if ($group_creation_done == 'done') {
                return;
            }

            if (WC_VERSION < '3.0.0') {
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $product_id = $item[ 'product_id' ];
                    $quantity = apply_filters('wdm_modify_total_number_of_registrations', $item[ 'qty' ], $product_id);
                    $product_type = wdmGetProductType($product_id);
                    $group_registration = isset($item[ 'Group Registration' ]) ? $item[ 'Group Registration' ] : '';
                    //$courses = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($product_id, '_related_course', true));
                    $courses = '';
                    if ($product_type == 'variable-subscription') {
                        $variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
                        if (!empty($variation_id)) {
                            $courses = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($variation_id, '_related_course', true));
                        }
                        $product_id = $variation_id;
                    } else {
                        $courses = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($product_id, '_related_course', true));
                    }
                    if (!empty($courses) && $group_registration != '') {
                        $uid = $order->get_user_id();
                        $user1 = new \WP_User($uid);
                        $user1->add_role('group_leader');
                        $user1->remove_role('customer');
                        $user1->remove_role('subscriber');
                        $group_data[ 'leader' ] = $uid;
                        $group_data[ 'course' ] = $courses;
                        $this->wdmCreateLearndashGroup($group_data, $order, $order_id, $quantity, $product_id, $product_type);
                        update_post_meta($order_id, 'wdm_successful_group_creation', 'done');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($items as $key_item_id => $item) {
                    $key_item_id = $key_item_id;
                    $product_id = $item[ 'product_id' ];
                    //$quantity = $item[ 'qty' ];
                    $quantity = apply_filters('wdm_modify_total_number_of_registrations', $item[ 'qty' ], $product_id);
                    $product_type = wdmGetProductType($product_id);
                    $group_registration = isset($item[ 'Group Registration' ]) ? $item[ 'Group Registration' ] : '';
                    $courses = '';
                    if ($product_type == 'variable-subscription') {
                        $variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
                        if (!empty($variation_id)) {
                            $courses = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($variation_id, '_related_course', true));
                            $product_id = $variation_id;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $courses = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($product_id, '_related_course', true));
                    }
                    if (!empty($courses) && $group_registration != '') {
                        $uid = $order->get_user_id();
                        $user1 = new \WP_User($uid);
                        $user1->add_role('group_leader');
                        $user1->remove_role('customer');
                        $user1->remove_role('subscriber');
                        $group_data[ 'leader' ] = $uid;
                        $group_data[ 'course' ] = $courses;
                        $this->wdmCreateLearndashGroup($group_data, $order, $order_id, $quantity, $product_id, $product_type);
                        update_post_meta($order_id, 'wdm_successful_group_creation', 'done');
                    }
                }
            }
            // exit;
        }
}
?>
```

This is not the complete Plugin file but it contains the method I want to call and the Class.

When I try to call the method this way I get the error message:

**'Fatal error: Cannot declare class wisdmlabs\ldgroups\WdmLdWooCommerce, because the name is already in use in C:\wamp64\www\meritmind\site\public\wp-content\plugins\ld-group-registration\modules\class-wdm-woocommerce.php on line 6'**

And when I remove the 'include' line I recieve this error message:

**'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WdmLdWooCommerce' not found in C:\wamp64\www\meritmind\site\public\wp-content\themes\meritgo\file.php on line 108'**

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. At one point it says I have not declared the class but when I declare the Class using include it says the Class is already declared.

Would really appreciate som help,

Best regards, Ledung

Comment: This is for 2 reasons, one you're using include, rather than include_once, two, your `class_exists('WdmLdWooCommerce')` doesn't work because that's not the full class name since you're missing the namespace.

Comment: That worked thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you would be so kind to leave an Answer so I can mark it as the solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

This fails for 2 reasons:

1) you're using include, rather than include_once. Using `_once` in general means the code isn't repeated if it's already been successfully used previously (which in this case would have stopped the class being defined a second time).

2) your `class_exists('WdmLdWooCommerce')` doesn't work because that's not the full class name, i.e. this is always returning false as 'WdmLdWooCommerce' doesn't exist, but `\wisdmlabs\ldgroups\WdmLdWooCommerce` should.